# nested JS Scripts are not included on wordpress page (using wp_enqueue_scripts in functions.php)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wp-enqueue-scripts

I have a problem with wordpress and wp_enqueue_scripts.

I want to **include selected scripts only on specific posts**.
For example: domain.com/post123/ <- script post123.js should be included. And to display the content within the post, I am using shortcodes.

**PROBLEM:** The scripts of the **second wp_enqueue_scripts** are not included (regarding the following setup)

**functions.php**

```
...
//in the functions.php I require 
require("assets/shortcodes/custom-shortcodes.php");
...
```

**custom-shortcodes.php**

```
function load_custom_shortcode_scripts(){
    if(is_single(208)) require("files-208/script-208.php");
    // others might follow
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_shortcode_scripts');
```

**script-208.php**

```
 function script_enqueue_stroop() {   
       wp_register_script( "gamescript_stroop", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/shortcodes/stroop/stroop.js', array('js-jquery') );

       wp_localize_script( 'gamescript_stroop', 'ajaxLoad', array( 'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

       wp_enqueue_script( 'gamescript_stroop' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueue_stroop' );
```

Everything is working fine until it reaches the wp_enqueue_scripts in the last file (208.php).

The stroop.js is not included in the code and it looks like wordpress is not processing the last wp_enqueue_scripts hook. If I write an "echo 'test'; in the script_enqueue_stroop() function, there is no response.

I thought it might be a problem with having a nested wp_enqueue_scripts within a wp_enqueue_scripts?

**Version 2**
And I tried to change the setup just slightly to prevent the nested wp_enqueue script like this:

**custom-shortcodes.php (adaption)**

```
function load_custom_shortcode_scripts(){
    if(is_single(208)){

        wp_register_script( "gamescript_stroop", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/shortcodes/stroop/stroop.js', array('js-jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'gamescript_stroop' );
        wp_localize_script( 'gamescript_stroop', 'ajaxLoad', array( 'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
        
       require("files-208/script-208.php");
    }
    // others might follow
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_shortcode_scripts');
```

Like this the file is included properly but I get this error:

```
XHR POST domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 Bad Request
```

by the way: Everything was working without any problems before I added the is_single(POSTID) ..., but the script was loaded on every single page (what is absolutely unnecessary)

Any ideas? I am struggling with this for a few days now and can't find a working solution.  Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Pages or posts? The is_single is only for posts

Comment: your right, thanks. Its actually only used for posts and the required script is working. So the code within the file is executed.